# How do I find common lines in two files

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++, comparison, file-compare

Let's say I have:

text.txt
with

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and another
text2.txt
with

```
9
4
2
1
7
```

And I want to extract the duplicates:

```
2
1
4
```

Note: I'm using windows, I want it to be as easy as possible

Answer (score 3):

#### I want to extract the duplicates

Use the following command line:

```
Findstr /i /x /g:text.txt text1.txt
```

Where:

> - `/I` Case-insensitive search
> - `/X` Prints lines that match exactly.
> - `/G:StringsFile` Get search string from a file

Source: [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Example:

```
F:\test>type text.txt
1
2
3
4
5
F:\test>type text1.txt
9
4
2
1
7
F:\test>Findstr /ixg:text.txt text1.txt
4
2
1
F:\test>Findstr /ixg:text1.txt text.txt
1
2
4
```

Note that there is no easy way to get the output in the order specified in the question:

```
2
1
4
```

as neither of the files contain the lines in that order.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Answer (score 0):

With a Unix environment (cygwin on Windows), I would first sort both files (`sort text.txt > text.txt.sorted`, idem for the second file), then use `comm -12 text.txt.sorted text2.txt.sorted`

Comment: Ok, some hints for Windows (get `comm` from Cygwin)

Comment: If you are using a Linux tools, there are easier ways of doing this -  for example **sort text.txt text2.txt | uniq -d** will concat the 2 files in memory, order them and list any duplicates.  I expect there are better ways of doing it under Windows.

Comment: I don't have a Windows box, but one way to do this with just Windows tools would be to concat the files together, then look for dupes with the following commands - copy text.txt text2.txt > both.txt   and then Get-Content both.txt |  Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | Select -ExpandProperty Name    (As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43808886/windows-powershell-to-find-duplicate-lines-in-a-file )

Comment: Windows have `sort` and `fc` to compare files. But on the command line it's better to use powershell which is far more powerful